# Sample code that hangs while executing on multiple processors

Tags: python, multiprocessing

While trying to run the following sample program, it hangs. I am new to Python multiprocessing and having trouble figuring this out. The program counts how many numbers are present within a given range in each row of data and I am working with the tutorial in https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/

```
import numpy as np
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def howmany_within_range(row, minimum, maximum):
    """Returns how many numbers lie within `maximum` and `minimum` in a given `row`"""
    count = 0
    for n in row:
        if minimum <= n <= maximum:
            count = count + 1
    return count

def main():
    pool = mp.Pool(2)

    # Prepare data
    np.random.RandomState(100)
    arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=[200000, 5])
    data = arr.tolist()
    print (data[:5])

    start = time.time()
    results = [pool.apply(howmany_within_range, args=(row, 4, 8)) for row in data]
    pool.close()
    end = time.time()

    print(results[:10], end-start)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It "hangs" because you're spinning a loop for a long time.  On my PC it finished in 30 seconds; you might just need to give it longer.

```
[[5, 5, 4, 0, 5], [7, 8, 5, 9, 0], [1, 4, 5, 5, 6], [8, 0, 2, 8, 0], [0, 4, 8, 5, 0]]
[4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2] 29.42530632019043
```

(Side note: I don't think your code is actually running in parallel right now; I assume the next part of the tutorial is going to be moving from `apply` to `apply_async`.)

Comment: Thanks for the observation and the side note, it indeed finishes in about 30 seconds on my PC too but surprisingly the sequential version finishes in 0.1 seconds. I will check out the apply_async.